# What happened to the barrier at the end of Digimon Tamers?

Tags: digimon-tamers

**Warning! This question contains spoilers; most are tagged, but the question's very substance is itself a spoiler.**

In one of the final scenes of *Digimon Tamers*, the entire cast is seen together:

> The kids are standing around the portal between the Real World and Digital World, and their Digimon--as well as Calumon and Impmon--are sucked into the portal to return to the Digital World. 
>  
>  Following this, after some time had passed, Takato returned to Guilmon's hole under the "house" in the park, where he found a portal to the Digital World, which we are to assume works just fine.

*(A more expansive explanation can be found [in the last two paragraphs of this synopsis](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Such_Sweet_Sorrow#Synopsis).)*

Firstly, how can the Real-Digital barrier—which Henry's dad says has "stabilized"—regress the Digimon? A barrier, by definition, should act as a split between the worlds, rather than a "vacuum". And second, if the barrier is so stable, why is Takato able to see it open again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the Digimon regressing:

> It seems to have to do with their initial bio-emerging being undone. And, since Digimon in the real world are synthesized false proteins, it would make sense that, without the Digital World being properly connected, their physical form would not be able to remain, so they reverted their evolution and returned to the Digital World.

As for the portal appearing:

> Shortly before we see it, we see Takato running through the park, when a [Digignome](http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/DigiGnome) flies overhead. Since they are known to be able to grant wishes, in both the Digital and Real Worlds, it would make sense that it granted Takato's implied wish to see Guilmon again, opening the portal for him.